# TypeError: _firebase_app__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default.a.auth is not a function

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I am installing Firebase to a tetris game I created. This is my first time doing such thing.  However, I came up with the following error:

```
TypeError: _firebase_app__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default.a.auth is not a function
```

The error is occurring in my App.js file.

```
import React from 'react';
import firebase from '@firebase/app';
import Login from './components/Login';
import Home from './components/Home';
import Tetris from './components/Tetris';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      user: {},
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.authListener();
  }
  authListener() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        this.setState({ user });
        //localStorage.setItem('user', 'user.uid');
      } else {
        this.setState({ user: null });
        //localStorage.removeItem('user');
      }
    });
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <div className="App">
    {this.state.user ? (<Home />) : (<Login/>)}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default App;
```

I did some research and tried the following:
-deleting node modules and reinstalling the following way:

```
$ npm install firebase --save
$ npm install firebase-admin --save
```

Does anyone know what is going wrong?  Any help or leads are appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: firebase-admin isn't meant for use a frontend apps, just backend.  It also causes problem for webpack.

Comment: You need to import firebase/auth as well. `import 'firebase/auth';`

Answer (score 0):

Add `import 'firebase/auth';` to the imports at the top and it should work fine.